# free groups , a question of listing elements and drawing multiplication table

Tags: abstract-algebra, free-groups

I'm requested to list the elements and draw the multiplication table for the group $\langle  a, b : |a| = 2 = |b|\rangle$ without any more details. But hence this group is infinite isn't it ?

while listing the elements i found $ = \{ a , b , ab , ba , aba , bab , abab , baba, \dots \}$

and so on ! I see that we must have an information about the order of $ab$ or $ba$?

Am I wrong ? Can anybody help me?

Comment: What do you mean by $|a|$?

Comment: Since $aa=1=bb$ any element must be a finite sequence of $ab$ or $ba$ and ending with $a$ or $b$. For example, $(ab)^ka$ or $(ba)^kb$.

Comment: @BISHD, order of $a$.

Comment: the order of the element a

Comment: The group is indeed infinite, so I too find it strange that you are being asked to draw the multiplication table for it.

Comment: This is called the [infinite dihedral group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_dihedral_group). It is indeed infinite. :)

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft so i'm not wrong , im gonna answer that it is infinite so we cant draw it's multiplication table. Thank u :)

Comment: @AymanHourieh thank u too :)

Comment: Did it say anywhere that the group was to be abelian?

Comment: You can't certainly draw a Cayley table of the given group (as most of us don't have infinite time to write it down...), but you certainly can give a rather satisfactory, complete description of its elements...

Comment: @TBrendle if it was so it would be easily solved!

Comment: @DonAntonio aha! i'm gonna do so

Comment: note that  $ab$ generate a copy of $\Bbb{Z}$ in that group, and, **all** length's odd normal forms are of order two: for example $(aba)^2=(aba)(aba)=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why the tag "free-groups"? Yours is not a free group but a free product, namely $\;C_2*C_2\;$ = the infinite dihedral group.

By the general theory, $\;C_2*C_2\;$ is an infinite group and the *only* elements with finite order are those who are conjugates to one of the elements in either factor.

Thus, if we put for the first factor $\;\langle a\rangle=\{1,a\}\;$ , and for the second one $\;\langle b\rangle=\{1,b\}\;$ , the *normal form* of an element in this group is of the form

$$abababa\ldots\;,\;\;\text{or}\;\;bababa\ldots$$

each of the two forms above being a **finite** word in those two letters, and the finite order elements are those of the form $\;g^{-1}ag\;,\;\;g^{-1}bg\;,\;\;g\in C_2*C_2\;$ , for example

$$ababa=(ab)a(ba)=(ab)a(ab)^{-1}\;,\;\;abababa=(aba)b(aba)=(aba)a(aba)^{-1}\;\ldots etc.$$